# Why does it open my old project every time I create new file after reinstalling Blender?

Tags: interface, customization

Every time I create new file this file keeps opening:

[image: Here is a picture of what opens]

Comment: This [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/60614/30849) will help you.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/186/how-to-change-blenders-default-startup-settings https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5574/how-to-remove-the-default-cube/5575#5575 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73825/blender-opening-with-a-scene-i-have-deleted

Answer (score 2):

I would guess you've had that project open, deliberately, since installing the new Blender? If so, you've probably pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, which saves the opened file as your start-up scene. You'll need to delete all objects and set it up as much as you can remember like the normal start-up scene, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, and say "yes" when it asks you if you want to "Save Start-up Scene."

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that a file was saved as startup file. To fix it you can load factory settings and save the file as the new startup file.

Alternatively you can delete the startup.blend file from the disk and let blender create a new one.

Depending on your operating system it will be stored in different places.

read: [where is the startup file stored](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23338/where-is-the-startup-file-stored)

And read the manual page for the startup file.(https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/data_system/files/startup_file.html)